# Replace words found in string with highlighted word keeping their case as found

Tags: php, replace, highlight

I want to replace words found in string with highlighted word keeping their case as found.

**Example**

```
$string1 = 'There are five colors';
$string2 = 'There are Five colors';

//replace five with highlighted five
$word='five';
$string1 = str_ireplace($word, '<span style="background:#ccc;">'.$word.'</span>', $string1);    
$string2 = str_ireplace($word, '<span style="background:#ccc;">'.$word.'</span>', $string2);

echo $string1.'<br>';
echo $string2;
```

**Current output:**

> There are `five` colors 
>   There are `five` colors

**Expected output:**

> There are `five` colors 
>   There are `Five` colors

How this can be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### To highlight a single word case-insensitively

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) with the following regex:

```
/\b($p)\b/i
```

**Explanation:**

- `/` - starting delimiter
- `\b` - match a word boundary
- `(` - start of first capturing group
- `$p` - the escaped search string
- `)` - end of first capturing group
- `\b` - match a word boundary
- `/` - ending delimiter
- `i` - pattern modifier that makes the search **case-insensitive**

The replacement pattern can be `<span style="background:#ccc;">$1</span>`, where `$1` is a backreference — it would contain what was matched by the first capturing group (which, in this case, is the actual word that was searched for)

**Code:**

```
$p = preg_quote($word, '/');  // The pattern to match

$string = preg_replace(
    "/\b($p)\b/i",
    '<span style="background:#ccc;">$1</span>', 
    $string
);
```

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JvoVVZ)

---

### To highlight an array of words case-insensitively

```
$words = array('five', 'colors', /* ... */);
$p = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $words));

$string = preg_replace(
    "/\b($p)\b/i", 
    '<span style="background:#ccc;">$1</span>', 
    $string
);

var_dump($string);
```

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mEWzu3)

Comment: how to use this for two or more word, say I want to replace `five` and `colors`

Comment: Loop them. `$words = array('five', 'colors', /* ... */); foreach ($words as $word) { /* preg_replace */ }`.

Comment: @TallboY: Actually, it can be much simpler. See my updated answer.

Comment: Its not working on case sensitive words. ex `string2 = There are Five colors` replace `five`

Comment: @TallboY: Can you give an example word that fails?

Comment: Its working but not working on partial word. Eg: replace `fiv`

Comment: @TallboY: If you want to replace partial matches, remove the `\b`s. Change the pattern to `/($p)/i`.

Comment: preg_quote($word, '/') didn't work for me. instead I replaced $p with '.$p.'
Also I am using $0 instead of $1, is there a difference?

Comment: @Halfacht: `$0` means the entire match, and `$1` means the first capturing group. Show your complete code - put it on eval.in and share link.

Answer (score 3):

str_replace - case sensitive

str_ireplace - class insenstive

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

Here is the test case.

```
<?php

class ReplaceTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testCaseSensitiveReplaceSimple()
    {
        $strings = array(
            'There are five colors',
            'There are Five colors',
        );

        $expected = array(
            'There are <span style="background:#ccc;">five</span> colors',
            'There are <span style="background:#ccc;">Five</span> colors',
        );

        $find = array(
            'five',
            'Five',
        );

        $replace = array(
            '<span style="background:#ccc;">five</span>',
            '<span style="background:#ccc;">Five</span>',
        );

        foreach ($strings as $key => $string) {
            $this->assertEquals($expected[$key], str_replace($find, $replace, $string));
        }
    }

    public function testCaseSensitiveReplaceFunction()
    {
        $strings = array(
            'There are five colors',
            'There are Five colors',
        );

        $expected = array(
            'There are <span style="background:#ccc;">five</span> colors',
            'There are <span style="background:#ccc;">Five</span> colors',
        );

        foreach ($strings as $key => $string) {
            $this->assertEquals($expected[$key], highlightString('five', $string, '<span style="background:#ccc;">$1</span>'));
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @argument $words array or string - words to that are going to be highlighted keeping case
 * @argument $string string - the search 
 * @argument $replacement string - the wrapper used for highlighting, $1 will be the word
 */
function highlightString($words, $string, $replacement)
{
    $replacements = array();
    $newwords = array();
    $key = 0;
    foreach ((array) $words AS $word)
    {
        $replacements[$key] = str_replace('$1', $word, $replacement);
        $newwords[$key] = $word;
        $key++;
        $newwords[$key] = ucfirst($word);
        $replacements[$key] = str_replace('$1', ucfirst($word), $replacement);
        $key++;
    }

    return str_replace($newwords, $replacements, $string);
}
```

Results

```
..

Time: 25 ms, Memory: 8.25Mb

OK (2 tests, 4 assertions)
```

Comment: The OP is aware of these functions. How does it answer the question?

Comment: He was trying to use str_ireplace as case sensitive when it isn't case sensitive. He asked for a function to get the case of the word.

Comment: No, he was trying to match the word case-insensitively and replace it with the exact same case that was found. `str_replace()` or `str_ireplace()` can't do this.