# Replace string of letters with same case as found in file using str_ireplace

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace a string of letters with their highlighted equivalent and still have them match to the case of the file.

Say there's my search query, which is "nice" and the text file contains "PDPFOW**NICE**PF". My `str_ireplace` successfully changes the "NICE" in the file to the highlighted "nice", but, as you can see, it no longer has the case it originally had in the file.

I can't use `strtoupper`/`strtolower` as the file could contain multiple cases, whereas it would originally be "PdpFOW**nIcE**PF" and I would need the highlighted version to be "nIcE".

I've already look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074488/replace-words-found-in-string-with-highlighted-word-keeping-their-case-as-found) but it doesn't help me.

So, how would I keep the case of the matched file string?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `preg_replace()`, turn on the case insensitive flag `i`, and refer back to the match. Here's a basic example using your test case and highlighting them with just asterisks.

```
$text1 = "PDPFOWNICEPF";
$text2 = "PdpFOWnIcEPF";
$search = "/nice/i";

echo preg_replace($search, "*$0*", $text1);
// PDPFOW*NICE*PF
echo preg_replace($search, "*$0*", $text2);
// PdpFOW*nIcE*PF
```

Comment: Hmmm... that's not working for me. Here, this is what I have: `preg_replace("/$explodePrimArgs[0]/i", "\033[43m" . "$explodePrimArgs[0]" . "\033[0m", $secondaryArgContents);`

Comment: It should look like this: `preg_replace("/{$explodePrimArgs[0]}/i", "\033[43m$0\033[0m", $secondaryArgContents);` or similar (I don't know your application, so I can't tell for sure). You need the curly braces to get the contents of an array within a string, and in the second argument, you need to replace with a backreference `$0` like I did in the above example.